# Twilio.Device.addcommand()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio

I'm working on creating a call queueing system using Twilio and .Net MVC, as well as Twilio's JS client.  Within the Twilio Client, I've been using the Twilio.Device object, and through Visual Studio's autocomplete feature, I came across "Twilio.Device.addCommand()".  I can't find any documentation on this method, and the only hint the autocomplete gives me is "addCommand(b, a)".  So does anyone have any advice about what this is used for?  I thought maybe I could add an additional method to the Twilio.Device object that would give me some added functionality, but I really have no idea what it is actually meant for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

addCommand is an internal function and not meant to be used by you in your application code.

However, I'd love to know more about what you were looking to do and see if maybe I can help you find a way to do it.

Hope that helps.